# Webcam repeating frame

Tags: webcam

I have recently installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS and while I tried to use webcam from cheese the first like 3-4 sec frame is repeated on loop. And also another problem with webcam is I tried using OpenCV for my DL project but the webcam won't capture anything. How can I solve it any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this.

Comment: At some point, the AI-generated answers below will be removed, so it's possible they'll already be gone by the time you check back in here. In that case, you'll just be thoroughly confused on what I'm talking about ;-).

Comment: I am facing the same issue with "Cheese" desktop app on Ubuntu 22.04. On the other hand, Google Meet, Microsoft Team etc are working fine. I guess the problem is with the "Cheese" desktop app.